# Обрезка изображения C#

Tags: c#, bitmap

При работе кода, сохраняется прозрачный прямоугольник. Как нужно сохранить объект или что-либо добавить, чтобы обрезка была правильной?

```
            int width = my_image.Size.Width;
            int height = my_image.Size.Height;
            Point point = my_image.Location;
            TakeScreenshot(Browser, savePlaceimg);

            var img = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(savePlaceimg));
            Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(point, new Size(width, height));
            Image src = Image.FromFile(savePlaceimg) as Image;
            Image target = new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
            {
                g.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(my_image.Location.X, my_image.Location.Y, target.Width, target.Height),
                                 cropRect,
                                 GraphicsUnit.Point);
            }

            target.Save(savePlace + "\\capCrop" + i.ToString() + ".png");
```

Comment: Когда то давным давно я писал скрипт для обрезки сканов фотографий. Я уже не помню, чего я там делал, но может вам чем то поможет https://tym32167.blogspot.com/2013/09/linqpad.html